# How to calculate pressure effect in quantum espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I want to calculate the electrical properties of cubic perovskite by varying the pressure.

For this can anyone tell me how to choose the parameters in the &cell section :
&CELL like
cell_dofree    = ????
cell_dynamics  = "bfgs"
press          =  0.00000e+00 (Targated Pressure)
press_conv_thr =  ????

Comment: Please use a `code` block.

Comment: Can you please tell in details?

Comment: @TarekAhmed so, you want to study your material's electrical properties (dos, band structure, etc.) under different external pressure using Quantum Espresso and you are looking for a sample input file or how to specify the pressure in the input file. Is that the case? Does [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/pressure-applied-dft-calculations-in-quantum-espresso?rq=1) help?